# How to group results of a query and return only one value of a specific column for the grouped results MYSQL

Tags: php, html

I have 3 MYSQL tables wp_tabl1, wp_tabl2, and wp_tabl3.

Each table has 5 columns as displayed below - `day, date, examtype, student name`

```
day |   date   | examtype | student name

Mon |01-07/2020|  type1   | George
Mon |04-07/2020|  type1   | Mary
Mon |04-07/2020|  type3   | Anne
Mon |04-07/2020|  type1   | Paul
Mon |04-07/2020|  type3   | Julian
Mon |04-07/2020|  type4   | Timmy
```

This is what I have so far:

```
<th colspan="5" style="text-align:center;"> <h2 class="exmm">EXAMS </h2> </th>
<tr>
 <th>Day</th>
 <th>Date</th>
 <th>Exam Type</th>
 <th>Student Name</th>
</tr>
  <?php
    global $wpdb;
    $result = $wpdb->get_results ( 
"SELECT * FROM wp_tabl1
WHERE date=DATE(NOW())
UNION ALL
SELECT * FROM wp_tabl2
WHERE date=DATE(NOW())
UNION ALL
SELECT * FROM wp_tabl3
WHERE date=DATE(NOW())
ORDER BY examtype ASC;" );
    foreach ( $result as $print )   {
    ?>
    <tr>
<td><?php echo $print->day;?></td>
<td><?php echo $print->date;?></td>
<td><?php echo $print->examtype;?></td>
<td><?php echo $print->studentname;?></td>
    </tr>
        <?php }
  ?>
```

PROBLEM - I don't wan't to return multiple values for the `examtype` given it has some duplicates.

Intended output in `HTML` format

```
day |   date   | examtype | student name


Mon |04-07/2020|  type1   | Mary
Mon |04-07/2020|          | Paul
Mon |04-07/2020|  type3   | Anne
Mon |04-07/2020|          | Julian
Mon |04-07/2020|  type4   | Timmy
```

Notice that it's returning one value of `examtype` for each group.

Please help me fix this, will appreciate your help.

Comment: make this in  php code,every thing else is messy

Comment: Use a variable to keep track of the last displayed `examtype` and only display the current value if it is different.

Comment: You should probably restructure the DB. Incremental tables are usually a bad design.

Comment: I am using incremental tables because I needed to break down the data into manageable chunks. I am completely fine with that.

Comment: I am still learning PHP. I have tried this with no success. I added this piece of code inside this `<td><?php echo $print->examtype;?></td>` replacing the php part with the code below still to no success. `<tr> <td colspan="5"><?php $i=0; foreach ($result as $print) { if($i==1) break; echo $print->examtype; $i++; } ?></td></tr>` Instead of returning the `examtype` once for each, it returns the same row multiple times. Help