# How to change the date format in a mysql query

Tags: php, mysql, date, datetime

I understand that this might already be having an answer somewhere but I have given this all shots to no success. Basically, I understand that MySQL stores data in the format YYYY-MM-DD. I am making this database query.

SELECT comp, date FROM wp_mytable
WHERE date=DATE(NOW())

Then I echo the date like so,

```
<td class="  column-comp"><?php echo $print->comp;?></td>
<td class="column-date"><?php date_format (new DateTime($print->date), 'd-m-Y');?></td>
```

this throws an empty date column.

When I change this to

```
<td class="  column-comp"><?php echo $print->comp;?></td>
<td class="column-date"><?php DATE_FORMAT("$print->date", "%d %M %Y");?></td>
```

I get this error

`Warning: date_format() expects parameter 1 to be DateTimeInterface, string`

What might be wrong here? I need to return the date in this format `d-m-Y`. Please

Comment: Can we see the rest of the code?

Comment: @Strawberry [It's in their previous question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62727112/how-to-group-results-of-a-query-and-return-only-one-value-of-a-specific-column-f) that I just closed as a duplicated question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are using `DATE_FORMAT` in `PHP` not `mysql`

Use like below

```
<td class="column-date"><?php date('d M Y',strtotime($print->date)); ?></td>
```

In your mysql you need to use like below

```
SELECT comp, DATE_FORMAT(date,"%d %M %Y") as new_date FROM wp_mytable WHERE date=DATE(NOW())
```

And in your first example remove `new DateTime`

```
<td class="column-date"><?php echo date_format($print->date, 'd-m-Y');?></td>
```

If above suggestion not work then share value of `$print->date`

Comment: @Maryongubo: I think you wanted to comment on your question and not in this answer.

Comment: My code above has a minor change I made which could be the cause of the date not working properly. I am selecting all tables like so - `SELECT * FROM wp_mytable WHERE date=DATE(NOW())` How do you change the date format when you're selecting all?

Comment: It should be `SELECT mt.*, DATE_FORMAT(mt.date,"%d %M %Y") as new_date FROM wp_mytable as mt WHERE date=DATE(NOW())`

Comment: This didn't throw any errors, just kept the format the same as that of the database `YYYY-MM-DD`

Comment: @Maryongubo: you will get in column `new_date`

Comment: I brought in the new_date as suggested and it worked! Thank you for helping @Niklesh Raut